# Trying to create a Trigger that will prevent specific Profile from creating a Topic

Tags: trigger, before-trigger

Here's the code that I come up.

```
trigger PreventTopic on Topic (before insert) {

    List<Profile> userProfile = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'test'];

    if(userProfile.size() > 0){
        if(userProfile.Id == UserInfo.getProfileId()){
            if(Trigger.IsInsert){
                for(Topic T : Trigger.New){
                    t.addError('Unable to Add Topic');
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm having an error Variable does not exist: Id

It's in **userProfile.Id** I'm new in SF development so explaining the cause and solution of the error will greatly help me.

Thank you!

Comment: N.B. as this is a before insert trigger, this line `if(Trigger.IsInsert){` is superfluous

Answer (score 2, accepted):

userProfile is a List - Array, so you have to fetch the "first" result as if you were from an array as such:

```
userProfile[0].id
```

I'd suggest you take a look at [Apex Code: The Basics](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Apex_Code:_The_Basics) and start out with [Trailheads](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/home)